# Excel copy rows & colums but skip blanks

Tags: excel

How can I copy the contents of this 'table' using a formula (not VBA or manual copy/paste) into a single column with no blanks?

**EDIT**
The content of the table will be changing so we want something dynamic

[image]

So the output would be something like:

```
Home
About Us
Financial Planning
Accounting Services
Contact Us
Our Company
Superannuation
Personal
Our Lcoation
...
... etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to get the result with a single and long array formula, however, I'd prefer a helper column.

Data region: `A1:E5`

`A6`, copied down: array formula

```
={SMALL((IF($A$1:$E$5="";"";ROW($A$1:$E$5)*1000+COLUMN($A$1:$E$5)));ROW()-ROW($A$6)+1)}
```

The formula is inserted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> from formula window. Curled brackets are inserted by Excel, not by a user.

Row number of a non-blank cell is multiplied by 1000, and column number is added to it, giving a unique number. The solution works if there are no more than 999 columns. The numbers are listed in the growing order.

`B6`, copied down:

```
=OFFSET($A$1;INT($A6/1000)-1;$A6-INT($A6/1000)*1000-1)
```

The number in the helper row is transformed into row and column offset.

[image]

[Example - Matrix_transposed_to_one_column.xls](http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Matrix_transposed_to_one_column.xls)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (down the column you want the data in):

=A1
=A2
=A3
=A4
=A5
=B2
=B3
=B4
=C2
..etc

Comment: That isn't going to skip blank cells though. The content in the table will be changing